# How can I check the size of the ROM chip which contains BIOS?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, linux-device-driver

I'm having an AMD ASUS mainboard which support 2nd gen of Ryzen and AMD promised that changing mainboard is not necessary for upgrading a new CPU. But according to this [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/aevnsp/not_all_am4_mainboards_might_support_ryzen_3000/), not all of mainboards can be upgraded to new Ryzen CPU due to the tiny size of the ROM chip. So I want to check my ROM chip's size to check if my mainboard is compatible with a new CPU. I'm using both Windows and Linux so I can use solutions of both OS.

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Just check if the mainboard manufacturer lists the CPU as supported for your mainboard.

Comment: I checked the specs of my mainboard, which told that my mainboard has 128M of ROM which contains firmware of a lot of hardwares. They didn't point out the exact size that the BIOS can be so it's kinda confusing.

Comment: The manufacturer of your mainboard should have a compatibility list on their web page detailing which mainboard supports which CPU. Use that list. Do not use the capacity your BIOS chip may or may not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MSSmBios_RawSMBiosTables for fetching the specified firmware table from the firmware table provider.

```
$Biostables = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName . -Namespace root\wmi -Query "
    SELECT * FROM MSSmBios_RawSMBiosTables"

Write-Host $("Your ROM Size: " + (64 * $obj.SMBiosData[9] + 64) + " KiB")
```